# Xmemory Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, recursion, exception

Whenever I run this code, I get `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6CA077375 in console test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`
coming from a file named "xmemory", what it is supposed to do is loop through different folders looking for a specified file, so it uses a bit of recursion, I'm not sure if that's part of the problem, it's still a WIP but I need to do something about the Exception first. I am using Visual Studio 17.3.0, C++20 Standard (/std:c++20) and MinGW gcc compiler, in case that helps

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

string endstr(string str, string delim) {
    int i = str.length();
    while (str[i] != delim[0])
    {
        if (i == 0) break;
        i--;
    }
    return str.substr(i + 1, str.length());
}

string start = "C:\\";
vector<string> explored;
string fl;
string *dir;
string getFile(const char* item, string startPath)
{

    for (const auto& file : directory_iterator(startPath))
    {
        fl = file.path().string();
        cout << fl << endl;
        if (fl == endstr(item, "\\")) {
            return fl;
        }
        else if (file.is_directory()) {
            if (find(explored.begin(), explored.end(), fl) != explored.end()) {
                getFile(item, fl);
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    explored.push_back(fl);
}

int main() {
    getFile("Terraria.exe", "C:\\");
}
```

Edit: debeg logs n stuff

Debug

```
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\willk\source\repos\console test\x64\Debug\console test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Avast Software\Avast\aswhook.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. 
'console test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The thread 0x5cec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF703A47415 in console test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

Build

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: console test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>console test.cpp
1>C:\Users\willk\source\repos\console test\console test\console test.cpp(14,25): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>C:\Users\willk\source\repos\console test\console test\console test.cpp(45): warning C4715: 'getFile': not all control paths return a value
1>console test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\willk\source\repos\console test\x64\Debug\console test.exe
1>Done building project "console test.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What does your debugger/logger say?

Comment: `str[str.length()]` is UB. You should write `int i = str.length() -1;` I think. Also, why is `delim` a string and not a `char`?

Comment: xmemory is in the deep-dark of the Standard Library implementation. If your program is failing in the Standard Library, odds are really good that the program was mortally wounded earlier in your code and the program staggered on for a while before collapsing and dying. The debugger's backtrace can show you how the program got from your code into the library code and let you see the arguments used. One of them is probably wrong. Why it's wrong may take more digging backward.

Comment: hol, up, lemme edit the post

Comment: Looks like you're using Visual Studio. When the program crashes it will give you a chance to stop and debug the program. Take it up on the offer and check out the Call Stack (the debugger's backtrace). Once you have identified the bad argument (@lorro 's picked off one likely candidate, but who says you've only got one bug?) you can set breakpoints and step through where the argument is set in the code to pinpoint where the program really broke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What goes wrong here is that `getFile` returns a bad string (uninitialized/garbage due to not returning any string) after it reaches `explored.push_back(fl);`. Then back in `main`, that string is destroyed, but that fails, so you're seeing an access violation coming out of the deep parts of the implementation of the destructor of `basic_string`.

In general, not returning something from a function that is supposed to return something, is a recipe for Bad Things happening.

While "debug output" rarely contains anything useful (unless you've put it there yourself), stack trace is generally useful because it helps you pin-point what the program was doing when it died:

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Compiler could pick this error off for you if you ask it: https://godbolt.org/z/sfhsqa6hn